# I'm getting my app crashed when I implement the method setSupportActionBar

Tags: java, android

Well, the thing is, if I erase that setSupportActionBar(toolbar) from the add_event activity, it works, the add_event activity opens and show all the buttons and textEdits on the screen, but dont show any button on the toolbar, just the toolbar, clean, and if I put that setSupportActionBar method, it crashes when I call the activity (add_event) .

Can someone explain whats happening? Thanks in advance :)

I've put some codes here, but you guys can download the entire project in my GitHub

https://github.com/dennysfarias/RemindIt

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //setting toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}


public void callactAddEvt(){
    Intent callAddEvt = new Intent(MainActivity.this, add_event.class);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(callAddEvt);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}


//put the options inside the 3dot menu
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            // User chose the "Settings" item, show the app settings UI...
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Settings Option Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.action_addevent:
            //User chose the AddEvent action, whom calls the com.ddtec.remindit.add_event activity
            callactAddEvt();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Add Event Option Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;
        default:
            // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
            // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Option Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
}
```

This is my MainActivity it works fine, I try this on my phone and it looks great.

Now i'm gonna show my second activity

```
public class add_event extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_event);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar2);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_add_event, menu);
    return true;
}




@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_addfinish:
            // User chose the Done action, saving the event...
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finish/Save Option Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;

        case R.id.action_cancel:
            // User chose the Cancel action, leaving without saving the current event...
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancel Option Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;

        case R.id.action_settings:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Settings Option Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;


        default:
            // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
            // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Option Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
}
```

My add_event activity layout file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".add_event">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"/>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar2">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:hint="Event Name"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:hint="Event Location"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:hint="Event Date"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="time"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:hint="Event Time"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText2" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:hint="Event Description"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And here my Style.xml

```
<resources>


<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppThemeWithNoAB" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/my_accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/my_primary_text</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/my_secondary_text</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>


</style>
```

The Logcat

```html
04-27 14:13:30.197 241-519/? D/RouteManager: doReconsiderRouting: DONE
04-27 14:13:30.197 241-519/? D/EVENT_THREAD: void CEventThread::run() Do poll with timeout: -1
04-27 14:13:30.197 241-520/? E/TinyAlsaStream: getFramesAvailable: Unable to get available frames
04-27 14:13:30.197 241-520/? E/TinyAlsaStream: getFramesAvailable: Unable to get available frames
04-27 14:13:30.197 241-520/? E/TinyAlsaStream: getFramesAvailable: Unable to get available frames
04-27 14:13:30.197 241-520/? E/TinyAlsaStream: getFramesAvailable: Unable to get available frames
04-27 14:13:30.207 525-1054/system_process V/WindowManager: Adding window Window{30cae9cd u0 com.ddtec.remindit/com.ddtec.remindit.add_event} at 8 of 27 (after Window{368d2628 u0 com.ddtec.remindit/com.ddtec.remindit.MainActivity})
04-27 14:13:30.327 11735-11735/com.ddtec.remindit D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-27 14:13:30.327 11735-11735/com.ddtec.remindit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.ddtec.remindit, PID: 11735
                                                                    android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler ClearAll in class com.ddtec.remindit.add_event
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(SupportMenuInflater.java:242)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:443)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:479)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:196)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:118)
                                                                        at com.ddtec.remindit.add_event.onCreateOptionsMenu(add_event.java:25)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3632)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:341)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:85)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:258)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:85)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:454)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:61)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5310)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
                                                                        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:114)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ClearAll [interface android.view.MenuItem]
                                                                        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
                                                                        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:643)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(SupportMenuInflater.java:240)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:443) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:479) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:196) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:118) 
                                                                        at com.ddtec.remindit.add_event.onCreateOptionsMenu(add_event.java:25) 
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3632) 
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:341) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:85) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:258) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:85) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:454) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:61) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5310) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699) 
                                                                        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:114) 
04-27 14:13:30.327 525-1034/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 1 com.ddtec.remindit/.add_event
04-27 14:13:30.337 525-1034/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 2 com.ddtec.remindit/.MainActivity
04-27 14:13:30.357 186-186/? I/upi_ug31xx: [get_daemon_uevent_request]: uevent_request = 0 (0000)
```

Comment: have you done any thing before posting question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `menu_add_event.xml` on line no:13 you have added 'android:onClick="ClearAll"'. This is causing the issue. Either remove that line or add the following function in your activity.

```
public boolean ClearAll(MenuItem item) { 
// actions 
}
```

Comment: Man, I cant believe, hahah
Just this... this was from a method that I used to clear my ListView when testing another things... I dont know why the IDE dont pointed as an error. But thank u, its working fine now :)